# How many wounds does each Ripper Swarms model have in 40K 8e?

Tags: warhammer-40k, modelling, tyranids

In the 8th edition Tyranid codex, on page 91 for Ripper Swarms, the unit description text is as follows:

> This unit contains 3 ripper swarms. It can include up to 3 additonal Ripper Swarms (Power Rating +2) or up to 6 additional Ripper Swarms (Power Rating +3). Each model is armed with claws and teeth.

This doesn't help that you can't buy Ripper Swarms on their own. So far, I've collected models that seem to be given as a bonus for buying other unit boxes. I've found that if I purchase a Termagaunt or Hormagaunt unit box, they'll come with three models of Ripper Swarms, but if I buy a Genestealers unit box, it will come with two models of Ripper Swarms.

How many models actually make up a Ripper Swarm? The unit description states a wounds of 3. Does that mean that each model has 3 wounds, and a full unit is nine models, for a total of 27 wounds?

Or are you supposed to collect a handful of these, and glue two or three onto a single base and then that base has 3 wounds? Which then a full unit is three bases, for a total of 9 wounds?

Comment: Technically, you can buy Ripper Swarms on their own... From Forge World. They're pretty cool, but much expensive! Early on you'll probably want to use 3-6 "models" on each base... but as you expand your army you'll end up with more and more (they do come with almost every kit) you may want to start making some "packed" bases just cause it looks cool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Ripper Swarm model has 3 wounds, as per the 8th edition codex.

A *unit* of Ripper Swarms is made up of anything from 3-9 *models* of Ripper Swarms. Each base is a model. Regardless of what you actually put on the model aesthetically, it will have 1 base, and that based model will have 3 wounds. So a unit composed of 3 models of Ripper Swarms would have 9 wounds total, 3 wounds each. A unit of 4 would have 12 wounds total, etc.

You can mix and match unit sizes to accommodate the number of models you have too. It's perfectly legal to run a unit of 3 Ripper Swarms and a unit of 4 Ripper Swarms in the same army.